# How to use a conditional statement in Android

Tags: java, android

I'd like to use a conditional statement to change the amount shown in a TextView. 
But when running the application, the second `else` statement is executed always. How do I correctly check for the conditional expression?

This is my code:

```
public class SecendActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtV_setText;
private EditText editText_factNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secend_activity);

    txtV_setText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_set);
    editText_factNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_text);
}

public void setText(View view) {

    if (editText_factNumber.equals(null)) {
        txtV_setText.setText("Change Text Behind");
    } else {
        txtV_setText.setText("Change Text Behind2");
    }

}
```

Comment: `if(objectReference.equals(null))` can never evaluate to `true`. It can only be `false` or throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above you are referencing the object or view EditText, not its contents.
You're probbably looking for

```
editText_factNumber.getText().toString()
```

Comment: Special Thanks to You dear Friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a EditText (the object) with null, so if the layout "secend_activity" has the EditText "number_text" it will never be null it will throw and exception.